# mysql multiple collation

Tags: mysql, collation

I have table with translations to 10 languages table(id, language_id, translation_text) it has charset utf-8 how can i query this table with different collations so in every language sorting would be according to their language rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a collation when you perform the query:

```
SELECT translation_text
FROM translation
WHERE language_id = 42
ORDER BY translation_text COLLATE latin1_german2_ci
```

See [Using COLLATE in SQL statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html).